# Variables from separate file loaded during NPM script execution

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

I have a file (`.env`) of environment variables defined at the root of my NPM module which looks like this:

```
FOO=bar
BAZ=zoo
```

I would like to have these variables made available when I run the module's `package.json` scripts.

Here's an attempt from my `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "foo": "source ./.env && echo $FOO"
  }
  ...
}
```

But, when I run `npm run foo` I get this error:

```
sh: 1: source: not found
```

How can I make `$FOO` available in this context?

A cross-OS solution would best, but for now I'm running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)?

Comment: I saw dotenv, but didn't see a way for it work directly embedded in the `scripts` section. In my case, I'm not trying to run a node.js program...just a bash script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think NPM has a built-in for that, but you can prefix all your scripts with a minimal export command:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "foo": "export $(cat .env | xargs) && echo $FOO"
  }
}
```